# Clear table values on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table that I populate via ajax call

Here is table code

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Ф.И.О</th>
        <th scope="col">Дата рождения</th>
        <th scope="col">Телефон</th>
        <th scope="col">График</th>
        <th scope="col">Адрес</th>
        <th scope="col">Паспортные данные</th>
        <th scope="col">Мед Книжка</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="people" style="overflow: auto;">

</tbody>
```

And here is code of js script to populate it

```
function AllPeople() {
let getPeopleUrl = '/peopleforworks/index';
$.ajax({
        url: getPeopleUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#people tr").remove();
            var list = data;
            for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
                var tableData = '<tr>' + '<td>' +
                    (i + 1) +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td > ' +
                    list[i].FIO +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td > ' +
                    moment(list[i].Birthday).format('DD/MM/YYYY') +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' +
                    list[i].TelephoneNumber +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td > ' +
                    list[i].WorkTime +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' +
                    list[i].Adress +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' +
                    list[i].PassportData +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' +
                    list[i].MedicalBook +
                    '</td>'
                    +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#people').append(tableData);
            }
        }
})
```

}

It works great and data is passing to table

But when I call this table (it's on modal) second time it's not clear values in tbody

I tried to do it like this `$("#people tr").remove();`, but it not works and I have no errors.

How I can clear values correctly?

Comment: `$("#people tr").remove();` should work, However you can use `$("#people").empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#people").empty();
```

Comment: This helped me. Thank's

Comment: @eugene you need to mark this answer as approved. by clicking on tick sign

Comment: @eugene people will stop helping other people if they are not rewarded accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all the rows.Then use below code.

var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.clear().draw();

For more information follow api link 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()